# webpack --watch で build.js ファイルが生成されません

Tags: webpack

以下の手順では生成されます。
`$ webpack`

以下のコマンドでは `build.js` が作成されません
`$ webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --watch --config webpack.config.js`

`webpack.config.js`の中身

```
// webpack.confing.js

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    filename: 'public/build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          babelrc: false,
          presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            '@babel/preset-react'
          ],
          plugins: [
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {
              legacy: true
            }],
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {
              loose: true
            }]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?modules']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  }
}
```

`$ watch`時のログ

```
$ webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --watch --config webpack.config.js
 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9000/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from path
i ｢wdm｣: Hash: 969fbd8febed56bc8d48
Version: webpack 4.20.2
Time: 2582ms
Built at: 2018-10-10 18:22:34
          Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
public/build.js  1.29 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = public/build.js
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/mobx-react/index.module.js] 43.2 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/punycode/punycode.js] 14.3 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:9000] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 7.78 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 ./src/app.js 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/app.js] 2.73 KiB {main} [built]
    + 25 hidden modules
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

各バージョン

```
"webpack": "^4.20.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
```

最新バージョンではwatch時にファイルが生成されなくなったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

**`webpack --watch`と`webpack-dev-server`は別物です。**`webpack-dev-server`はブラウザからアクセス可能なサーバーを提供する代わりに、生成物をファイルシステムに保存する機能はありません（参考：[Write bundle to disk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/62)）。ファイルに保存してもらうためには`webpack --watch`とする必要があります。

webpack-dev-serverを使いつつ生成物をファイルに保存してもらう方法としては、[write-file-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin)を使う方法があるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。元々の仕様で分かれているのですね。 `webpack-dev-server` や、その他ベストプラクティスなどを見ながら色々試してみます。